# How to check connection is made into a server when using PrincipalContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, principalcontext

I need to change the password of a windows user in a machine which is connected in the same network. For that I am connecting the machine using `PrincipalContext`method, then get the specified user and finally change the password.

```
 private bool ChangeUserPassword(string serverName,string serverip,string adminUserName, string adminUserPassword, string userName, string newIISPassword)
    {                                   
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, serverName, adminUserName, adminUserPassword))                
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
            {
                user.SetPassword(newIISPassword);
                user.Save();
            }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I won't get the connection to the server when I am providing 'ServerName' but works with 'ServerIp' and vice versa.
If it is connected `context.ConnectedServer` will show the server name, if not it is showing unknown path or bad username error.

If connection is not made I could use serverIp as parameter

```
 using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, serverIp, adminUserName, adminUserPassword))
```

For that I tried `if( context.ConnectedServer != serverName)` to know the connection is not working and put the above code inside it.But it will return error since there is no ConnectedServer.

How can I check the connection to the server is made or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS server may not be fully configured on your network.  Please use the FQDN of your machine name.

[image: Example of Full Computer Name]

Comment: I am developing this application for a client. I can't insist them to make this change on their network. So finding a solution in code level is the only option for me right now.

Comment: I am not saying to make changes on their network.  I am just saying they should enter/used the **full computer name**.